# how to make a html iframe 100% width and height?

Tags: html, iframe

how do I make an iframe 100% width and height of the window?

Comment: Some suggestions over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-100-height

Comment: This isn't really the same question as the duplicate for several reasons: a) this question asks "how" while the other question asks "where: (as in "which browsers"), b) this question came a full year before the other "question", and c) the other question is lower quality, poorly written and formatted. d) two questions with the same answer do not make duplicates (ie 1+1 and 4/2 are both 2 but aren't the same question).

Comment: @mikel answer is not posted into the other question. I guess is not the same "how to construct a 100% iframe" AND "how to make 100% width, probably after it exists on the page".

Answer (score 76):

This code probably help you.

```
<iframe src="" onload="this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height;">
```

Comment: this.width to set the width of this tag . screen.width to get the screen width value . this code make this tag (iframe) width = screen width and it's height = screen height - i am sorry

Comment: `screen` is the actual screen and not the browser window, so in most cases the browser window will be smaller than the screen size.

Comment: This is working for me on most scenarios, obviosly in scenarios with javascript. Looking for solution like this for non-js. Thanks a lot.

Comment: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight is far more accurate.

Comment: @Kristian Williams - I've tried and i guess are not for the same proposal. Still think screen.height is the best way to try force an alement to the 100% of space.

As example, a "fake" dns redirection between ports uses a iframe loading right website at right port, like open myweb.com:8080 while accessing 8080.myweb.com as regular port 80 web access. 

The 100% auto-fill funcion is perfect in that case, so the content will being adapted to screen instead to iframe proportions.

Comment: <iframe name="Stack" src="http://stackoverflow.com/" style='height: 100%; width: 100%;' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe">...</iframe>

Comment: Working for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Lucky, why do you post this in the comment and not as an answer? It is not a good solution either, the height is very small for me.

Answer (score 26):

Answering this just in case if someone else like me stumbles upon this post among many that advise use of JavaScripts for changing iframe height to 100%.

I strongly recommend that you see and try this option specified at [How do you give iframe 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height) before resorting to a JavaScript based option. The referenced solution works perfectly for me in all of the testing I have done so far. Hope this helps someone.