# How do you give iframe 100% height

Tags: html

I'm trying

```
<iframe height="100%" ...>
```

but it still doesn't resize it. When i try the height in pixles it works.

edit: 100% seems to be working on IE but not firefox

Comment: Can you please show the HTML code you are working with? Setting something to 100% height will give it the same height as it's PARENT. What is the parent of the iframe?

Comment: @Elad, he had included the iframe tag declaration, but without the code formatting it wasn't visible (I had thought the same as you)

Comment: @elad there is not html code ive only got html head body iframe. it seems ot be working in IE though not firefox

Comment: Try setting a height for the body.

Comment: For those looking around in the future, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height/27853830#27853830

Comment: @JoshCrozier Is it usual to close 4 year old questions as duplicates in favor of a more recent one and then link to your own answer? Seems a bit shady.

Comment: @dtech I can agree with that. It may be shady, but my intent was to direct future visitors to the more popular question with an array of different answers/solutions.. you could bring it up on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This question appeared above the "more popular" answer in my Google Search, and in my opinion, is actually the better worded question: "How do you give iframe 100% height" vs "Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%"

Comment: according to [1] `100%` is not correct, `width` and `height` must be  integer. [1]  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#attr-dim-width

Comment: I finally found the answer to that question that actually works : 

- Position the iframe in the top left corner of the div.
- Make it 100% of the height and width of the div.
- Add padding to the top of the div equal to the aspect ratio of the iframe (for HD videos, 56.25%, or 9 / 16 * 100).

`.responsive-iframe {
 max-width: 100%;
 padding-top: 56.25%;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.responsive-iframe iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none"></iframe>
```

Be aware that this will by default place it in the upper-left corner of the page, but I guess that is what you want to achieve. You can position with the `left`,`right`, `top` and `bottom` CSS properties.

Comment: Wow! After so many failed attempts (including some not-so-elegant JavaScript suggestions) trying to make IFrame's to size to a correct height consistently, I stumbled upon this answer, and so far it seems to work very well! Thank you for saving me hours and hours worth of additional research. I cannot figure out why others do not have this as an answer??? By the way, absolute positioning can be easily managed by placing iframe in a relatively positioned div - that's what I am doing - absolutely position it at top:0, left:0 in a parent div that has position:relative; Seems to work for me.

Comment: The <div> in which the iframe is located also has a height: 100%, thanks, your solution worked! I embedded a SSRS inside a ASP.NET page.

Comment: doesnt work with me :( similar problem :(

Comment: Nice one ... looks fine in all major browsers. Even IE!

Comment: Isn't working in Firefox v28.

Comment: Perhaps it's because this question / answer is so old, but `position:absolute` isn't necessary, in fact it's not a great idea unless you actually need to position it explicitly... just set the height on the parent container.

Comment: Put this inside another div with the position set to relative.Make that div have a height of 100% and it scales! Perfect.

Comment: Working for react-native-webview as well.

Answer (score 67):

The problem with iframes not getting 100% height is not because they're unwieldy. The problem is that for them to get 100% height **they need their parents to have 100% height**. If one of the iframe's parents is not 100% tall the iframe won't be able to go beyond that parent's height.

So the best possible solution would be:

```
html, body, iframe { height: 100%; }
```

*…given the iframe is directly under body*. If the iframe has a parent between itself and the body, the iframe will still get the height of its parent. One must explicitly set the height of every parent to 100% as well (if that's what one wants).

Tested in:

`Chrome 30`, `Firefox 24`, `Safari 6.0.5`, `Opera 16`, `IE 7, 8, 9 and 10`

PS: I don't mean to be picky but the solution marked as correct doesn't work on `Firefox 24` at the time of this writing, but worked on `Chrome 30`. Haven't tested on other browsers though. I came across the error on `Firefox` because the page I was testing had very little content... It *could* be it's my meager markup or the `CSS` reset altering the output, but if I experienced this error I guess the accepted answer doesn't work in every situation.

**Update 2021**

@Zeni suggested this in 2015:

```
iframe { height: 100vh }
```

...and indeed it does the trick!

Careful with positioning as it can potentially break the effect. Test thoroughly, you might not need positioning depending of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It looks like having a parent with `height: 100%` does the trick. `position: absolute` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This worked for me. Another solution which works is set height in style of iframe to 100vh.  <iframe src="/mysite.com" width="100%" style="height: 100vh;"></iframe>  (vh is viewport height)

Comment: "they need their parents to have 100% height" is not true. iframes take their height from the content if set to 100%, not from the container.

Comment: css solutions do not work when the content of the iframe changes (eg, when the iframe content makes ajax calls etc.)

Comment: I tried most suggestions here without success, and just before moving on I noticed @Zeni 's comment: setting `height: 100vh;` in my CSS solved the `height=100%;` being ignored issue (even though I did not have a `viewport` line in my HTML file).  I did not need positioning ...

Comment: More here re: `vh` (viewport height): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100

Comment: vh is just viewport height so if the content is longer than the viewport than this will not be sufficient

Answer (score 34):

The iFrame attribute does not support percent in HTML5. It only supports pixels.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp