# How can I set a 100% height on my Custom Google search iframe?

Tags: html, google-custom-search

I am trying to make 100% height for custom google searh iFrame height. I am not able to control the height. When ever the result displays the iFrame height shows 1860. Below the results it shows big gap. But I want to make the height 100%. It should be automatically control the height depend on the results.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57Yqj/)

```
<iframe width="795" scrolling="no" 
  height="1860" frameborder="0" name="googleSearchFrame"
  src="http://www.google.com/cse?cx=018208848722929177185%3A1jfp3jdh3vw&amp;cof=FORID%3A9&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;q=itwin&amp;sa=&amp;ad=n9&amp;num=10&amp;rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsgopalweb.internalitwin.com%2Fsearch.php%3Fcx%3D018208848722929177185%253A1jfp3jdh3vw%26cof%3DFORID%253A9%26ie%3DUTF-8%26q%3Ditwin%26sa%3D"
 marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"
 allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see your frame code as referenced in "Please check below frame code", but you may want to check out following - very likely you will find your answer there.

[How do you give iframe 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height)