# How to make width and height of iframe same as its parent div?

Tags: html, iframe, width

I have a iframe inside a div. I want the size of iframe to be exactly the size of its parent div. I used following code to set the width and height of iframe.

```
<iframe src="./myPage.aspx" id="myIframe" 
    style="position: relative; 
            height: 100%; 
            width: 100%' 
            scrolling='no' 
            frameborder='0'">
```

But width of iframe is not same as div, also both horizontal and vertical scrollbar are displayed.

Comment: well you missing `;` after `width`, `scrolling` and `frameborder` and there is `'` in front of the `position`....

Answer (score 58, accepted):

you have a lot of typos.

a correct markup should be like:

```
<iframe src="./myPage.aspx" id="myIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
...
</iframe>
```

also, if this frame already has an ID, why don't you put this in **CSS** like this (from a separate stylesheet file):

```
#myIframe
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

and **HTML**

```
<iframe src="./myPage.aspx" id="myIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" > ... </iframe>
```

mind that `scrolling` & `frameborder` are `iframe` attribute, not `style` attribute.

Comment: For me position:absolute worked  instead of position:relative. Got the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height

Answer (score 13):

Since we are in the age of CSS3, you can do this by using viewport units. These units allow you to specify sizes in terms of percentages of the viewport width and viewport height. This is the user's viewport, also known as screen. However, in all major browsers I've tried it, if you put an iframe inside a div, which is inside another div and positioned relative, the viewport units are relative to this div. And since 100 viewport height units mean 100% height, you can do like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative">
        <iframe style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:100vh;" src="http://anydomain.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I find this to be the best solution possible, since it is **cross-domain**, and displays exactly like you want it without any javascript or other complex stuff.

And most importantly, it works on all browsers, even mobile ones (tested on android and iphone)!

Comment: what `cross-domain` have to do here? did you mean `cross browser`? btw: using percantage units is a lot easier and safer for this scenario rather than using view-port units.

Comment: A height of `100vh` only works if the `iframe` is fullscreen otherwise it will be the height of the entire window, not necessarily the content. The same as height of `100%`.

Answer (score 3):

To set dynamic height -

1. We need to communicate with cross domain iFrames and parent
2. Then we can send scroll height/content height of iframe to parent window

## 1 For communication

I prefer - https://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/

## 2 Implementation

To detect iframe height change - Uses https://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcj/css-element-queries/master/src/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ternarylabs/porthole/master/src/porthole.min.js"></script>
```

**For rest of the implementation refer gist -**

```
https://gist.github.com/mohandere/a2e67971858ee2c3999d62e3843889a8
```

### Parent window:

```js
(function(){

'use-strict';

//This soultion we have used  - https://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/
// example - 

var iFrameId: 'guestFrame',
window.onload = function(){
    // Create a proxy window to send to and receive
    // messages from the iFrame
    var windowProxy = new Porthole.WindowProxy(
        'http://other-domain.com/', iFrameId);

    var $viewPort = $('#'+iFrameId);
    // Register an event handler to receive messages;
    windowProxy.addEventListener(function(messageEvent) {
      
      if( messageEvent.data.height == $viewPort.height() ){
        return;
      }
        $viewPort.height(messageEvent.data.height);
    });

    Porthole.WindowProxyDispatcher.start();
};


})();
```

### iframe window:

```js
(function(){

'use-strict';

/**
 * Iframe to Parent window communication
 * sample iframe- <iframe id="guestFrame" name="guestFrame" src="http://other-domain.com/">
 * </iframe>
 * Uses https://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/
 * Uses https://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/  
 */
window.onload = function(){

  var proxy = window.proxy  = new Porthole.WindowProxy('http://parent-domain.com/');
  proxy.addEventListener(function(messageEvent) {
      // handle event
  });

  //Height setup
  var iframeHeight = 0;
  
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  new ResizeSensor(element, function() {
    
    var scrollHeight = $('body').outerHeight();
    if (iframeHeight === scrollHeight) return false;
    
    iframeHeight = scrollHeight;
    proxy.post({
      height: scrollHeight,
    });
    
  });

  Porthole.WindowProxyDispatcher.start();

};

})();
```

Comment: The "Run code snippet" is giving some error if possible kindly resolve the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an iframe that has the width and the height to its parent container, you can use this approach:

```
<style>
    .parent-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
    }

    .parent-container iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="parent-container">
    <iframe src="https://your-iframe-url.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

The `padding-top` rule decide the `width` and the `height` of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

in my case only assigning to vh did work, so maybe try the same.

for example create the below class

```
.test-class{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
```