# Demandforce appointment form, integration with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I am developing a website for dentist friend. So far it's looking good, I am using Wordpress along with the [enfold theme](http://www.kriesi.at/themedemo/?theme=enfold).

One of the requested features for this website is to include the DemandForce appointment form, so customers would be able to schedule their appointments inside the new website.

I visited Demand force and found that the way to include their contact form is by:

- Copying the following CSS file into the header `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//www.demandforce.com/widget/css/widget.css" />` Which I did by modifying header.php
- Adding the following script into the body; `<script type="text/javascript">
  d3cp_bid = 'private'; // Business ID in DemandforceD3
  //d3cp_appt_source = 'My Website';  //optional. See Instructions.
  //d3cp_appt_returnpage = 'your_page_url'; // Optional. See Instructions.
  //d3cp_appt_postdata = 'false';  // Optional. See Instructions.
  </script>
  <script src="//www.demandforced3.com/b/burlingamesmile/scheduler.widget" type="text/javascript"></script>`
  Which I also did simply by created a raw text field and inputing it.

The result of this can be seen [here](http://www.southcitysmile.com/preview/schedule-appointment/). As you probably notice the form is not correctly formatted and I don't really understand why. I checked the source code, and both the CSS file and the script are where they should, so I don't quite get the displaying issues.

Since I couldn't figure it out this way, I tried another idea. The actual reservation form is hosted [here](https://www.demandforce.com/b/burlingamesmile/schedule). The good thing about that form is that is actually responsive. So I created another page with the following:
`<iframe src="https://www.demandforce.com/b/burlingamesmile/schedule" width="1000" height="1500"></iframe>`. How this looks can be observed [here](http://www.southcitysmile.com/preview/schedule-appointment-2/)

This behaves *ok*. But the frame size doesn't adjust well to different screen sizes (smartphone, tablet, etc.) I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height) one, but it doesn't do the trick.

At this moment I am running out of ideas, so any comments/help is greatly appreciated, as always.

Thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your custom CSS section of the theme:

`iframe, object, embed {
    max-width: 100%;
}`

Worked for me, making the content within the iframe responsive.