# Make an iframe height automatically extend to the bottom of the browser window?

Tags: html

I'm making a website ([codersdomain.site88.net](http://codersdomain.site88.net)) and I have an iframe that needs to extend to the bottom of my browser window. Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="./icon.png">
</head>
<title>Coder's Domain</title>
<body style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; height:100%;"
 background="BG.jpg">
<div align="center">

<iframe tabindex="-1" style="height:590px; width: 596px; overflow-y:'scroll' overflow-x:'hidden' " src="index_data.html"frameborder=0 ></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

can somebody tell me how I might make the height automatically extend to the bottom of the window?

```css
body { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; height:100%; }
iframe {height:590px; width: 596px; overflow-y:'scroll' overflow-x:'hidden'}
```

```html
    <body
     background="BG.jpg">
    <div align="center">
    
    <iframe tabindex="-1" src="index_data.html" frameborder=0 ></iframe>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: Why not make a snippet and not use inline css?

Comment: because i like HTML, and am not good at css.

Comment: what snippet editor?

Comment: Next to the {} - it has `</>`

Comment: i feel very stupid but i have no idea what that is :|

Comment: Edit your question and look at the button bar. Visit [help] and take the [tour]

Comment: '-' i am still confused

Comment: See the snippet I made for you. I moved the inline style to the CSS stylesheet

Comment: um i actually just deleted it like a stupid XD could you do it again :- |

Comment: how would i make it into an html file, or what file would it be?

Comment: To use a CSS file, include it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` and put the stuff in it I put in the CSS frame in the snippet. That does not solve your issue, but makes it MUCH easier to inspect  and modify

Comment: well i just realized i could set the height to 100% and yeah i feel pretty dumb... `-`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you give iframe 100% height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the height to 100%

```
 <iframe tabindex="-1" style="height:100%;
 width: 596px; overflow-y:'scroll' 
 overflow-x:'hidden' " src="index_data.html"frameborder=0>

</iframe>
</div>
```