# Height equal to 100% is not working for IFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

Following by some topics on Stack Overflow like:

1. [Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100)
2. [How do you give iframe 100% height [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height)
3. [Make Iframe to fit 100% of container's remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height)

I wanted to nest iframe on my web page. I am using bootstrap to style web page, so I used following code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe id="iFrame1" src="<test_link_here>" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Unfortunately my iframe is not resized to full height. I would like somehow to resize it automatically to full height.
Do you know how I can acheive it?

Comment: height 100% wont works mostly. try **100vh**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want could actually be done by changing the `height : 100%;` value to `height : 100vh;`.The **vh** is a unit called ViewHeight, and your full screen height is actually 100vh;

Here is [a post](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/length) about length units from the Mozilla team.

Try this code :

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe id="iFrame1" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100vh;width:100%; border : 1px solid red;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help, but unfortuneatelly this code didn't fix the issue. The behabviour is still the same

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!