# Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, html-frames

Is iframe height=100% supported in all browsers?

I am using doctype as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

In my iframe code, if I say:

```
<iframe src="xyz.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

I mean will it actually take the height of the remaining page (as there is another frame on top with fixed height of 50px)
Is this supported in all major browsers (IE/Firefox/Safari) ?

Also regarding scrollbars, even though I say `scrolling="no"`, I can see disabled scrollbars in Firefox...How do I completely hide scrollbars and set the iframe height automatically?

Comment: See actually I do not have all the browsers installed..Also different versions..also just wanted to ensure that it is kind of standard..

Comment: You could also try it in a css validator.

Comment: Yes, that does not give any error/warning...But my question is do all browsers actually apply 100% height?

Comment: For me this answer worked fine:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height

Comment: I finally found the answer to that question that actually works : 

- Position the iframe in the top left corner of the div.
- Make it 100% of the height and width of the div.
- Add padding to the top of the div equal to the aspect ratio of the iframe (for HD videos, 56.25%, or 9 / 16 * 100).

`.responsive-iframe {
 max-width: 100%;
 padding-top: 56.25%;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.responsive-iframe iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 351, accepted):

You could use frameset as the previous answer states but if you are insistent on using iFrames, the 2 following examples should work:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

An alternative:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

To hide scrolling with 2 alternatives as shown above:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:150%;width:150%" height="150%" width="150%"></iframe>
</body>
```

Hack with the second example:

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:150%;width:150%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="150%" width="150%"></iframe>
</body>
```

To hide the scroll-bars of the iFrame, the parent is made `overflow: hidden` to hide scrollbars and the iFrame is made to go upto 150% width and height which forces the scroll-bars outside the page and since the body doesn't have scroll-bars one may not expect the iframe to be exceeding the bounds of the page. This hides the scrollbars of the iFrame with full width!

Comment: Sounds good..Just one question though...Why do we need to use style="height:100%;width:100%;" when we are anyways saying iframe height="100%" width="100%"

Comment: Also only IE is not taking 100% height (takes around 200px ht)...FF and Safri take all the remaining height..

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky Yeah, thanks for letting me know that! I've updated the post now!! @hmthr Your first question relating the double tags is because earlier browsers do take the "height" and "width" tags but don't work well with the style tags! About the IE bug, I would prefer you to stick with the first code for that case.

Comment: I've just made a change to the second code which seems to clear up the 200px bug in IE. I was seeing a gap on the right hand side. Now it is clear!

Comment: To hide the scrollbars you can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691873/safari-chrome-webkit-cannot-hide-iframe-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: There you go, most likely the final edit! It is all set and working. iFrame width and height to cover 100% of the web browser area / working area and the scrollbars are hidden by pushing them outside the bounds of the BODY. Thanks and it was great helping you! :D

Comment: @hmthr Your question "Is iframe height=100% supported in all browsers", the answer is most probably yes (this code provided above works in all browsers that you want it to work!) and the next question "How do I completely hide scrollbars?" can be shown by the last to code pieces which hide the scroll bars! :D

Comment: To get the iframe to properly use 100% the parent needs to be 100%. In newer doctypes the html and body tag are not automatically 100%. When I added height:100% for html and body then it worked flawlessly. So, the correct answer for the question, I think, is the answer from rudie, except that I had to keep my xhtml doctype. Also, note that the overflow rules are then not necessary. Scrollbars then work as intended - automatically.

Comment: This only works in quirks mode.  Doesn't work in Standards mode.  To make it work in standards mode you have to set the height on HTML and BODY to 100% also.

Comment: FYI  "HTML <frameset> Tag. Not Supported in HTML5." - ref. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp.

Comment: width and height are digits without units. They are in pixels. width="100%" is not valid HTML5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: some can't touch body, wrong code

Answer (score 219):

### 3 approaches for creating a fullscreen `iframe`:

---

- #### Approach 1 - [Viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

  In [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you can use [viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) such as `height: 100vh`.

  Where `100vh` represents the height of the viewport, and likewise `100vw` represents the width.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qegaezk6/)

  ```css
  body {
      margin: 0;            /* Reset default margin */
  }
  iframe {
      display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
      background: #000;
      border: none;         /* Reset default border */
      height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
      width: 100vw;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <iframe></iframe>
  ```

---

- #### Approach 2 - Fixed positioning

  This approach is fairly straight-forward. Just set the positioning of the `fixed` element and add a `height`/`width` of `100%`.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7xspqw0/)

  ```css
  iframe {
      position: fixed;
      background: #000;
      border: none;
      top: 0; right: 0;
      bottom: 0; left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <iframe></iframe>
  ```

---

- #### Approach 3

  For this last method, just set the `height` of the `body`/`html`/`iframe` elements to `100%`.

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/txacs8to/)

  ```css
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;         /* Reset default margin on the body element */
  }
  iframe {
      display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
      background: #000;
      border: none;         /* Reset default border */
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <iframe></iframe>
  ```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of option 1... I used width:100% and height:100vh because the source I was pulling was pretty wide and the iframe is contained in a div.  Excellent solution.  Thank you.

Comment: adding ```display: block``` did the trick to prevent having a double-scrollbar

Comment: One more approach could be found here (use padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */):
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp

Answer (score 55):

I ran into the same problem, I was pulling an iframe into a div.  Try this:

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100vh;"></iframe>
```

The height is set to 100vh which stands for viewport height.  Also, the width could be set to 100vw, although you'll likely run into problems if the source file is responsive (your frame will become very wide).

Comment: seamless is not supported in any browser as far as i know

Comment: After spending more time than I'd care to admit fidgeting around with this problem, this is EXACTLy what I needed. Except instead of a website I used another HTML file, which required a minor adjustment to the viewport height and now it's good to go. Thank you!

Comment: I got a double-scrollbar using this solution but otherwise it worked

Answer (score 47):

1. Change your DOCTYPE to something less strict. Don't use XHTML; it's silly. Just use the HTML 5 doctype and you're good:

```
<!doctype html>
```

2. You might need to make sure (depends on the browser) that the iframe's parent has a height. And its parent. And its parent. Etc:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: The important part here for me was that the html and body tag needed height:100%. Thanks.

Comment: Setting just body works in Chrome, but not in other browsers.

Comment: [Here are 2 alternative approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27853830/2680216).

Answer (score 37):

This worked very nicely for me (only if iframe content comes from the **same domain**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcHeight(iframeElement){
    var the_height=  iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    iframeElement.height=  the_height;
}
</script>
<iframe src="./page.html" onLoad="calcHeight(this);" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="the_iframe" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

Comment: This will only work if the `iframe` `src` is on the same domain as the parent page, otherwise you will get a permission denied error on `contentWindow.document`.

Comment: Took a little to make this work inside of Wordpress, I just added a shortcode in my plugin. WORKS LIKE A CHARM.

Comment: It works. but the problem is that it will not be recalculate the height on each inner iframe postback. Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 13):

```
<iframe src="http://youraddress.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;">

</iframe>
```

Answer (score 10):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;            /* Reset default margin */
}
iframe {
    display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
    background: #000;
    border: none;         /* Reset default border */
    height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

Answer (score 8):

> `<iframe src="" style="top:0;left: 0;width:100%;height: 100%; position: absolute; border: none"></iframe>`

Answer (score 6):

The following tested working

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" src="index.html" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: There are 14 other answers already here.  Can you explain how your answer is better or at least different from the 14 others?

Comment: I tried this and some very interesting results came up. The parent frame and iFrame were merged together!

Answer (score 6):

To get a full screen iframe without a scrollbar inside the iframe use the following css. Nothing more is required

```
iframe{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw
        }
    
    iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**You first add css**

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
```

**This will be the html:**

```
 <div style="position:relative;height:100%;max-width:500px;margin:auto">
    <iframe src="xyz.pdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://embedresponsively.com/

This is a great resource and has worked very well, the few times I've used it. Creates the following code....

```
<style>
.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } 
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
</style>
<div class='embed-container'>
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/66140585' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the answer of Akshit Soota:
it is importand to explicitly set the height of each parent element, also of the table and **column** if any:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; height: 100%; overflow:hidden; ">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style=" height: 100%">
<div style=" height: 100%">


    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%" cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" height="100%">
                <iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;margin: 0px; padding:0px;" 
                        width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
                        src="http://www.youraddress.com" ></iframe> 
            </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise code.  It does relies on a jquery method to find the current window height. On load of iFrame it sets the height of the iframe be the same as the current window. Then to handle resizing of the page, the body tag has an onresize event handler which sets the iframe's height whenever the document is resized.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my I frame is as tall as your page</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onresize="$('#iframe1').attr('height', $(window).height());" style="margin:0;" >
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="yourpage.html" style="width:100%;"  onload="this.height=$(window).height();"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

here's a working sample: http://jsbin.com/soqeq/1/

Answer (score 1):

if your parent `<div>` fill the height with the multiple solution mentionned here.

Then you could also use something like

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
    <iframe style="flex:1 1 0%;" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Another way to  build fluid full screen `iframe`:

---

### Embedded video fills entire `viewport` area when page loads

Nice approach for landing pages with video or any embedded content. You can have any additional content below of embedded video, which is revealed when scrolling page down.

#### Example:

CSS and HTML code.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 56vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.embwrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.embwrap .embcell {
    width: auto;
    background-color: black;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.embwrap .embcell .ifrwrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
    background-color: black;
}

.embwrap .embcell .ifrwrap iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="embwrap">
    <div class="embcell">
      <div class="ifrwrap">
        <iframe webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1920" height="1440" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5SIgYp3XTMk?autoplay=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;showsearch=0&amp;rel=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;fs=1"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<article>
  <div style="margin:30px; text-align: justify;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis lorem orci, rhoncus ut tellus non, pharetra consequat risus. </p>
    <p>Mauris aliquet egestas odio, sit amet sagittis tellus scelerisque in. Fusce in mauris vel turpis ornare placerat non vel purus. Sed in lobortis </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Please note, you might need some javascript for Firefox. There is common issue with iframe height on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me (but for "same-domain"):

```
function MakeIframeFullHeight(iframeElement){
    iframeElement.style.width   = "100%";
    var ifrD = iframeElement.contentDocument || iframeElement.contentWindow.document;
    var mHeight = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( ifrD.documentElement).height );  // Math.max( ifrD.body.scrollHeight, .. offsetHeight, ....clientHeight,
    var margins = ifrD.body.style.margin + ifrD.body.style.padding + ifrD.documentElement.style.margin + ifrD.documentElement.style.padding;
    if(margins=="") { margins=0;  ifrD.body.style.margin="0px"; }
    (function(){
       var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(ifrD.readyState  == 'complete' ){
            iframeElement.style.height  = (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle( ifrD.documentElement).height) + margins+1) +"px";
            setTimeout( function(){ clearInterval(interval); }, 1000 );
        } 
       },1000)
    })();
}
```

you can use either:

```
MakeIframeFullHeight(document.getElementById("iframe_id"));
```

or

```
<iframe .... onload="MakeIframeFullHeight(this);" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe, percentage values are no longer allowed.
 But the following worked for me

```
<iframe width="100%" height="this.height=window.innerHeight;" style="border:none" src=""></iframe>
```

Though `width:100%` works, `height:100%` does not work. So `window.innerHeight` has been used. You can also use css pixels for height.

Working code: [Link](https://github.com/informationdiet/informationdiet.github.io/blob/master/index.html) Working site:
[Link](https://informationdiet.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can can call a function which will calculate the iframe's body hieght when the iframe is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function iframeloaded(){
       var lastHeight = 0, curHeight = 0, $frame = $('iframe:eq(0)');
       curHeight = $frame.contents().find('body').height();
       if ( curHeight != lastHeight ) {
           $frame.css('height', (lastHeight = curHeight) + 'px' );
       }
    }
</script>

<iframe onload="iframeloaded()" src=...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery,

```
$('iframe').on('`enter code here`load', function(){
   $(this).css('height', $(this).contents().find('body').height());
});
```