# Why does iframe height 100% not work in an XHTML page?

Tags: html, iframe, xhtml, height

I'm playing around with an iframe that embeds a second page and just displays a short header above the iframe.

In one test setup, `height="100%"` worked correctly and in another setup it didn't and then [I noticed that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-100-height) the difference was the the one document where the iframe height always was set to about 150px was an XHTML document, and the document where it works doesn't have a DOCTYPE set.

So, this works: (height fully scaled to window)

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<h1>Wrapper Header ...</h1>
<hr/>
<iframe src="/jenkins" width="100%" height="100%">
  <p>iframes not suppoerted</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and this *doesn't* (height about 150px or so)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<h1>Wrapper Header ...</h1>
<hr/>
<iframe src="/jenkins" width="100%" height="100%">
  <p>iframes not suppoerted</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Display is the same in IE8 and FF5.

**Why** is it that the height percentage no longer works if I have XHTML doctype?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the page renders in standards mode with a valid DTD. The reason it worked in the other mode is because it was in quirks mode.

The reason why it works in quirks mode is because browsers were very lenient and not strict in the past, and thus people did `height="100%"` without specifying heights on html/body in the past.

The proper way to do it now is to set heights on the html/body. Try something like `html, body { height:100%; }`

The iframe might also need to be the immediate child in order for this to happen. Alternatively you can probably position it absolutely/fixed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the html/body height thing.

Comment: But do you need to set html/body height of the page that contains the `iframe` or the page that gets loaded within it?

Comment: Height 100% did not work, but using position absolute on the iframe worked in my case. Thanks!