# iframe 100% height issue

Tags: html, css, iframe

In this issue here I want the iframe to occupy the whole blue box.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYvK2/1/)

I have given width and height 100% but height has no effect. Any fix?

Comment: It's weird that a short answer will be converted to comment, even when there is no need for more explanation...

Comment: check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height

Comment: this one answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height

Comment: please check: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height

Answer (score 1):

Change your `display: table-row` to `display: block`. Also notice that height percentage to fill a div will work only of the parent container has a fixed height, either by `px` or something else, or in percentage `%`. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/jYvK2/9/)*** is the corrected fiddle.

Else you may try with your own layout. But add `position: absolute;width:300px;height:250px;` to your div `#two`. If you want to display some element using percentage, then it's parent container's attributes (width and height) should be defined, and only then, the child will stretch.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/jYvK2/11/)*** is the fiddle.

Comment: The reason I have given `display:table-row` is that the blue box takes the rest of the portion. I have just added a fiddle in my question i.e. it is quite basic. In my project the height of `wrapper` is equal to the browsers height and height of blue box is equal to browser's height minus `50px`. Now, remember browser can resize so the height of blue is also going to change.

Answer (score 0):

Give `<div id="two">` a `height:100%` in css. The iframe needs to fill the parent element but without a height set it wont.

Comment: That's the only solution I come around. But it is working only in firefox. Did you checked in chrome? `id="two"` is taking up 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code slightly in this fiddle. Basically your blue box div needed a height value. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYvK2/5/)

Comment: Its dynamic, it can be any so I can't pre-set it. That's the reason I used table layout ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the blue div `position: relative` and use the following css for the iframe:

```
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#two {
    position: relative;
    /* other CSS for #two */ 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYvK2/6/)

Comment: Your solution puts the iframe absolute to body. So it is not working.

Comment: @MotaBOS if you set the div where the `iframe` is in to `position: relative` it will set it absolute to that div. so that would be: `#two { position: relative; }`. I'll update my answer to make it more clear.