# HTML5 iframe relative size

Tags: css, html, iframe

It seems like HTML5 does not support relative height of iframes. When adding

to my document height in the css rule

```
#content{width:100%; height:100%;border:1px solid;}
```

is ignored by firefox. Without the doctype, it works.

EDIT: I found that I needed to add size of html element as well. Now it works.

Comment: You might want to rephrase this as a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5867985/509706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the iframe's position absolute:

```
#content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```