# Vimeo iframe as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I going to make a website that has a video as a background.

I want to load the video from vimeo but I havent found the best way to put it fullscreen.

i´m trying to add a css to the iframe but it doesn´t work at all:

```
iframe{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Do any of you know the best way to embed it as a background without using plugins or html5 to avoid problems with IE.

thank you!

Comment: possible but it doesn´t have to do anything with my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height/27853830#27853830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4279a/)

Wrap it in a div and set that also to 100%, 100%

```
iframe, div {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @fxg no problem ^_^ happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<iframe src="vimeo.path"></iframe>
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
#container {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

DEMO:

http://jsbin.com/utezov/4/embed?live

Comment: @Neal It does but the iframe in the background doesn't ;)

Comment: I get a "This page aint here" message.

Comment: You demo now has a DIV **covering** the iframe... you cant stop the video or anything else on the video for that matter....

Comment: @Neal Af the question states `has a video as a background` imo that means that there is an overlaying div/content-holder over the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/47922974" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/47922974">Jape 'Scorpio'</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/fergalbrennan">Fergal Brennan</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Now i just took a video from vimeo.
maybe set a class to the iframe like

```
<iframe class="fullvideo">
```

and set the css like:

```
iframe.fullvideo {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an ID to identify this bg iframe:

```
<iframe id="bgiframe">...</iframe>
```

and redefine this iframe in this way:

```
html, body, p, div, span, table, td 
/* Add other elements... These are explicit defined since ie6/7 doesn't support * selector */ 
{
   z-index: inherit;
   background: transparent; /* this is important to see-through normal elements */
}

#bgiframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

`z-index: -1;` is for take this element under every other elements.
`background: transparent;` for every other elements is to see through and see video as background.

This can be an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4KHET/2/