# I would like to set an iframe as a background using css

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Dear programmers @ stackoverflow,

Is it possible to set an iframe as a background using css?

I explain myself a bit further:

Today I have a div in my website called div="lead"
When I use that div in my html files the picture 'lead_photo.jpg' displays as a background.
The code I use in my css file to obtain that is:

```css
#lead { position: relative; float: left; clear: both; 
        width: 100%; height: 300px;
        background: #dbdbdb url(../images/lead_photo.jpg) center no-repeat; }
```

So far so good.

Now, I would like to display my "google business view-tour", which I should  integrate using the iframe link, as a background on my website in stead of the current photograph.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363092/vimeo-iframe-as-background

Comment: You'll have to position the iframe absolutely and with a z index lower than the other elements.

Comment: remember to add your own answer and mark solved, it helps the community ;)

Comment: Hi @filip , I want to do the same with what you want to achieve but i cant find still figure out how to do it ? do you have that answer already? my goal is to make the google map iframe as background to my section.

Answer (score 1):

With this text in the css it worked just fine for me:

```
#iframe { position: absolute; float: left; clear: both; width: 100%; height: 350px; z-index: 0; left no-repeat; }
```

afterwords I used `div="iframe"` in html.

Thanks 4 helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

you try it this CSS to set background image us.
also, check the **path of your image** correct or not.

```
#lead { 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    clear: both; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 300px;
    background-image:  #dbdbdb, url(images/lead_photo.jpg);
    background-position: center no-repeat; 
}
```

you set color & images to us this CSS and set background image.