# Iframe working but Height always increase

Tags: javascript, iframe

Hello after hours of search i found a script that works for my iframe exept a little problem it never stops it increases the height with no stop... here is the code
i add this script at my page i want the iframe

```
<script>
  function alertsize(pixels){
    pixels+=0;
    document.getElementById('myiframe').style.height=pixels+"px";
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myHeight = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
    if(myHeight != document.body.scrollHeight){
      myHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
      parent.alertsize(myHeight);
    }
  },500);
</script>
```

here is iframe:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://www.altasoft.gr/hermes/index.html"
        name="myiframe" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Also noticed this problem some time ago. I pseudo-solved it by setting a fix height for my Iframe at page load in relevance to the device's screen size. Dunno if this actually can be fixed finally.

Comment: Use a css reset and reset the value for iframe.
Something like iframe{ margin:0 padding:0 height:0 width:0}

Comment: thx for fast answer Rinku /  Corsair  can you write me an exaple? because im not sure how to do it ... thx!

Comment: Can you explain what your objective is?

Comment: If your objective is that your iframe occupies 100% height and width there are easiest solutions with css http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-100-height

Comment: I want an iframe that will increase or decrease height depending on the page it loads

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `height="100%"` in your markup. Change it to a fixed pixel value, and the script will start working. So change `height="100%"` to `height="1"` or whatever, the exact value doesn't really matter.