# Delphi webbrowser clone video include frame size

Tags: delphi, video, twebbrowser

I dont know how to explain this, but here it goes.

Have you seen a delphi code that uses twebbrowser and displays only the frame(height and width) of the video?

I meant if I browsed in youtube the small window of the twebbrowser will resize itself to the size of the video of youtube video.

Even to the other websites that has a video, the twebbrowser automate to resize itself like the video size of the website.

i hope you've seen a code like that one,

thanks

Comment: Well, I can think of navigating to a HTML content [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/25u6rT4u), but it's the source used for embedding specific video given by the page. I don't know how would you do this dynamically without modifying content at loading time (which is also not that easy to be universal) to something [`like this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5868263/960757).

Answer (score 2):

I've seen something similar. If you use Adobe Flash to play the video, you could use `Navigate` to a URL directly to the `.swf` file and this would show the file sized to the size of your TWebBrowser component. If you also add what is needed to suppress the border of the TWebBrowser component, it might result in what you're looking for.