# Chrome Extension - iFrame auto-height

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have created an iFrame in my Google Chrome Extension popup and applied CSS so it has no border and height: 100%.

However, it appears with a limited height and shows a vertical scrollbar.

How do I set it to adjust to the height of the loaded HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, [source here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fit-iframe-to-content/).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){

        var iFrames = $('iframe');

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
              iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

               iFrames.load(function(){
                   setTimeout(iResize, 0);
               });

               for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
               }

            } else {
               iFrames.load(function() { 
                   this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
               });
            }

        });

</script>
```

Comment: You placed this before the iframe, right? Also, make sure it is not interfering with any other scripts.

Comment: I've done so, even loading it externally (necessary for Chrome Extensions).

Comment: I'm not sure what to say - it works for me.. This post might be of some help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```