# how can i switch web pages of the website automatically , which i have created, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create website which will mostly look like a presentation with no user input.The user must vist to my site and he will be able to see images sliding and after regular interval of time the page must change automatically.
I want to know how can i switch pages of my website using javascript at regular interval of time.

Comment: Have you looked into the `setTimeout()` function and/or [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.231.3A_Navigate_to_a_new_page) yet? If not, [what else have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Yea i wouldn't stay on a site long if it kept jumping pages just to change an image lol. 

check out some image sliders and stuff with jquery.

Comment: I don't think "switch pages automatically" is good. You should "switch images automatically" instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in one page. Essentially, every TIME_PER_PAGE interval, you switch the "page" div out, and sub in the next page. The inline stylesheet ensures that only the current page is visible and that it takes up the full size of the screen.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body, html { 
                height: 100%; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0; 
            }

            .page {
              top: 0; 
              left: 0; 
              width: 100%; 
              min-height: 100%; 
              position: absolute; 
              display: none; 
              overflow: hidden;
              border: 0;
            }

            .currentPage { 
              display: block; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var TIME_PER_PAGE = 2000;
            window.onload = function() {
                var pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page'),
                    numPages = pages ? pages.length : 0;
                    i = -1;

                function nextPage() {
                    if (i >= 0)
                        pages[i].classList.remove('currentPage');

                    i++;
                    pages[i].classList.add('currentPage');
                    if (i < numPages - 1)
                      setTimeout(nextPage, TIME_PER_PAGE);
                }

                nextPage();
            }
        </script>

        <div class="page">Page 1 Content</div>
        <div class="page">Page 2 Content</div>
        <div class="page">Page 3 Content</div>
        <div class="page">Page 4 Content</div>
        <div class="page">Page 5 Content</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, this is the way to go. This should be a jsfiddle.

Comment: how do you get it to loop over again?

Comment: replace i++ with i = (i + 1) % numPages; Get rid of "if (i < numPages - 1)" to make sure setTimeout executes every time.

Comment: In addition to this I was also helped by the following post to get my formatting right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this maybe - where 2000 is 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location='http://google.com.au';}, 2000);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Where by "something like this" you mean `setTimeout(function() { document.location='http://google.com.au';}, 2000);`? (The code you've shown will set the location immediately, it won't wait two seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` would be nice.
For example:

```
var interval = setInterval(switchPage, 2000)
function switchPage(){
    //with use of Jquery
    var active = $('.page.active'), next = active.next();
    if(next.length !== 0){
        active.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn(function(){
            active.removeClass('active');
            next.addClass('active');
        });
    }
}
```