# can percentage be provided in iframe tag of html5 tag for height and width?

Tags: html, iframe

I am creating an application for dynamic graphs in html5 and javascript. I want my 4 graphs on the screen to be displayed as 4 quadrants on any device, this application works. This is code I have created

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<iframe src = "file.html" height="500" width="500" align = "left" frameborder = "0"> </iframe>


<iframe  src="file2.html" height="500" width="500" align = "middle" frameborder = "0"></iframe>
<iframe  src="file3.html" height="500" width="500"align = "middle" frameborder = "0"></iframe>

<iframe  src="file4.html" height="500" width="500"align = "middle" frameborder = "0"></iframe>


</head>
</html>
```

Comment: your application "works". now what's the problem?

Comment: He mentioned the question in the title. He wants to use percentages instead of exact pixel values for height and width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can provide `height` and `width` in `%` to iframe. Although there is a catch to it.

If you Give CSS to iframe like this

```
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

you will notice only the `width` attribute makes changes, The `height` attribute will not make any changes.

To make that work you have to specify `height` for the parents of iframe, in this case `body` and `html` . So your CSS would now be

```
html,body{

    height: 100%;
}

iframe{
    width:60%;
    height:70%


}
```

Now changing `height` in iframe will reflect changes.

Here is a  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLTz7/)

Comment: Welcome, please mark as answer if it proved helpful

Answer (score 4):

## 2021 - update:

An easier solution would be to use flex so all 4 iframes will take up 25% of the viewport width:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
iframe {
   min-width: 25%;
   height: 300px;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <iframe src="file1.html" height="500" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <iframe src="file2.html" height="500" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <iframe src="file3.html" height="500" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <iframe src="file4.html" height="500" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

---

### *Original answer:*

Use percentage instead of fix width:

```
<iframe src="file.html" height="500" width="24%" align = "left" frameborder = "0"> </iframe>
<iframe src="file2.html" height="500" width="24%" align = "middle" frameborder = "0"></iframe>
<iframe src="file3.html" height="500" width="24%"align = "middle" frameborder = "0"></iframe>
<iframe src="file4.html" height="500" width="24%"align = "middle" frameborder = "0"></iframe>
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FWPq2/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: width="100%" is not a valid value for the attribute in html5. I don't know whether browsers tolerate it, it seems they do, but it's not valid.