# iframe height 100% not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a problem with iframe height. Below is the piece of code with iframe height 100%

```
 <iframe id="iframeid" src="#" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframeid">
</iframe>
```

But, iframe not fit with the entire screen height. I am getting 1/4 th screen

So, I used Jquery here to identify the screen height and set it to iframe height.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iframeWin = screen.height;
    $('#iframeid').height(iframeWin);
});
```

Now the height got expanded to some extend (screen height), but the problem is I am getting more height. I am seeing some scrolling too..

Is there any correct way to fit the iframe on entire screen?

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshmsp/sfrq96tr/7/)

Comment: you're seeing expanded size because you're using the full screen size.. you need to take into account other elements on the screen which are `pushing` your iframe down

Comment: I don't mean to be THAT guy but, this question has been asked a few times before. [Have a look here for a number of solutions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height) :)

Comment: Is Preetesh.Dev's answer is the correct way to do this?

Comment: @UIDesigner - It's one of many ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the whole screen height. The proper way to do this is using `window` height. So the proper code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window_size = $(window).height();
    $('#iframeid').css('height', window_size);
});
```

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotwbtgo/).

Comment: Is that the correct way ?

Comment: Yeah, of course it is. Read this documentation to learn more: http://api.jquery.com/height

Comment: Also I wanted to add that `screen.height` returns the height of the screen itself. So that means if you're using a screen whose resolution is 1366x768 than `screen.height` will return 768.