# Set iframe height in pixels

Tags: css, iframe, height

I want to show a top bar on my page with height 72 pixels height and then load an iframe beneath which fills the full page (minus height of the topbar).

Before I can even start to take my topbar into account...somehow my iframe ignores any height attribute I set to it:

```
width='100%' height='1200' style='overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%' 

or 

width='100%' height='100%' style='overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%'
```

I have been reading this post: [Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height)

But no luck. See it live here: http://www.trouwlocaties.com/extpage.aspx?id=315&t=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the first removing `height:100%` from the `style`, now the iframe should be 1200px of height.