# Safari is ignoring set height for iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, height, safari-extension

I have extension in which I set height for extension iframe and it works nice in Chrome.

But I have a problem in Safari 9.1.2. Safari is ignoring set height and expand iframe to full browser height.

```
<iframe id="tools" src="safari-extension://.../tools.html" style="height: 400px !important;">
  #document
    <html>
      ...
    </html>
</iframe>
```

I set height for iframe by JavaScript:

```
tools.style.setProperty("height", request.height + "px", "important");
```

or

```
tools.style.height(request.height + "px");
```

and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("tools").style.height = "50px"
```

^ correct syntax

```
tools.style.height = request.height + "px";
```

or

```
tools.style.height = request.height;
```

should do the trick.

depending on the value of request.height

Comment: I created iframe element before as:
`tools = document.createElement("iframe");`

I mean it doesn't work with dynamically variable and constant.
I think that this is due to the features of Safari work.

Comment: @Grinv, is this on your desktop er mobile device?

Comment: on Desktop. Safari 9.1.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100
Maybe one of these guys found a solution.