# Getting an App running in an Iframe at full size/width

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

Trying to insert an AngularJS app into an IFrame, by default it only appears squashed and small.

With some tweaks it shows full with but not full height (even if height is set at 100%)

```
    <head>
    <title>My Ionic App HTML Webpage Title</title>
    <style>
    html,body{
    height:100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
        <iframe src="http://example.com/myapp/#/tab/chats" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
```

**EDITED & WORKING**

It was the CSS that I have placed in the head tags that sorted it

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100

Comment: Thanks, sorted now. Adding the 2nd part with CSS sorted it.

Comment: Glad that worked.