# Why iframe is bigger than body? iframe adds vertical scrollbar when 100vh

Tags: html, css, iframe

Suppose I have very simple markup. I want iframe to take 100% of screen height but setting `100vh` still adding scrollbar.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<iframe scr="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
```

But I see vertical scrollbar. Why is it showing and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Because of height.

Comment: by default, body have padding and maging. try to make it to 0 in the iframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply fix this issue , Just add a `float:left` or `display:block` to the `iframe`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<iframe scr="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add an answer like this.Maybe allso add a "overflow: hidden;" - but it allready should work out like a charm with this answer.

Comment: overflow hidden may be remove the iframe ends

Comment: Accepting answer for `display: block`.

Comment: @JishnuVS Can you please remove `-moz-box-sizing`, `-webkit-box-sizing` and all this vendor stuff? They are for extremely old browsers.

Answer (score 2):

`iframe` has default `display: inline` so changing `display` property to something like `display: block` fixes this issue.

Also if `iframe` is flex item (child of flex-container, adding `display: flex` for `body` in current case will make `iframe` a flex-item) it will also help because it will be implicitly blockified.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it to be full screen:

1. Add `display:block;`
2. Add the `'allowfullscreen'` attribute.

Change to:

```
<iframe scr="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Adding `allowfullscreen` didn't help me at all. Remove the height is non-sense. How it will help me to get 100% height of iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe scr="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
```

Comment: No, I want iframe to take 100% of screen height, updated question.

Comment: Ok, Use float:left;

Comment: Thanks, the only valid answer for now. Can you explain why is this happening?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot control the height of a cross domain content. If you try to upload an outsource html page into your html page, you cannot control the content size, only if you have access to the source content or server. Then you can add some JS and you'll not have extra scrolling.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: I'm not trying to control height of domain content. I just want `iframe` to get 100% of screen height regardless of content.

Comment: that's the problem: "regardless of content". You cannot know what is the iframe content height.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I want to set 100% of screen height.

Comment: I've tried to do what you said, make it 100 %, but you set your div 100%, it will not display the 100%.

Comment: maybe you'll find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100

Comment: The iFrame attribute does not support percent in HTML5. It only supports pixels. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp

Comment: Where do you see attribute `width` and `height` in my question?

Comment: if you have vertical scroller, than is a matter of height.

Comment: Hey, I can't specify percentage and other than `px` unit in `iframe` in `width` and `height` **HTML attributes**, but I can specify any units in **CSS 
`width` and `height` properties**. Does this makes sense for you? Can you please also launch code in my question and accepted answer to see how my issue is resolved?

Comment: I've sent the same explanation in comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853830/3362989
Problem solved, than all good:)