# Full Height iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html

In wordpress I'm using a plugin that create this iframe:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" src="http://...k.jpg&amp;is_stereo=false" width="100%" height="1200px"></iframe>
```

This is the array of the php page:

```
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
   'img' => '',
   'video' => '',
   'pimg' => '',
   'stereo' => 'false',
   'width' => '100%',
   'height' => '1200px',
   ), $atts );
```

and this the php code:

```
    <iframe width="<?php echo $a['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $a['height']; ?>" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen src="<?php echo $iframe_url; ?>"></iframe>
```

The width is perfect and responsive.

I need to have a full height iframe. How?

Comment: `'height' => '100vh',`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100)

Comment: Something seems wrong with the code formatting but I can't edit the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can try and see if this works:

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <iframe width="<?php echo $a['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $a['height']; ?>" scrolling="no" style="height:100%;width:100%" allowfullscreen="1" src="<?php echo $iframe_url; ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="1" src="http://...k.jpg&amp;is_stereo=false" style="height:100%;width:100%"  width="100%" height="1200px"></iframe></div>
```