# Content.jsp is displayed in a small left top corner area, not full of the page with white background. How do I set the CSS?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Here is my Index.html; it made up of four JSP files. The three JSP files are placed correctly with the black background, and only content.jsp is weird to show only in the left top corner part with the white background.

```
    **#content{
      float: left;
    }**
<div id="header">
  <iframe frameborder="0" src="/header.jsp" name="header"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <iframe frameborder="0" src="/navigator.jsp" name="nav"></iframe>
</div>
**<div id="content">**
  **<iframe frameborder="0" src="/content.jsp" name="content";>**</iframe>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <iframe frameborder="0" src="/footer.jsp" name="footer"></iframe>
</div>
```

Content.jsp is below:

```
    li{
        list-style:none;
        padding:0px 5px;
        margin:0;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
<ul>
<c:forEach items="${page.bookList}" var="book">
<li>
    <a href="/book?method=book_detalis&b_id=${book.b_id}" ><img src="/${book.image_path}">
    ${book.name}<br>${book.price}</a>
</li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

I ask for a piece of HTML element properties code in Index.html or Content.jsp that makes content.jsp to display fully.

The problem screenshot is below:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is; but using multiple iframes to build the overall structure of a site (what it looks like here with your frames loading a navigation, a footer etc. by the names of it) is not a good way to go about things to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be nothing to specify the size of the `iframe` so it defaults to a small area.

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

See this question for more:
[Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100)