# Prevent iframe Vertical Scroll On Mobile

Tags: html, css, iframe

I added an `iframe` to a WordPress page template.
The iframe has a style of `min-height: 475px`.
I would add the `iframe` code, but it is proprietary to the company I work for.
The `iframe` looks great on desktop (100% page width, height looks great.
But I have a vertical scroll issue on mobile.

When viewing the page on mobile the `iframe` section scrolls vertically. No scroll bar, just vertical scrolling.
I want the `iframe` to fit the page perfectly on the mobile view so the `iframe` section does not scroll up or down.

I have tried adding/adjusting styles to the `iframe` such as: `max-height:100%`, `min-height: 663px`, etc...

So far no luck. 
When I increase the `min-height` the desktop view has more white space between the `iframe` div and the div below it, not good.

Any suggestion on how to remove `iframe` vertical scrolling on the mobile view?

Comment: Can u show us the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100)

Comment: Please add more information like screenshots and your codes. both HTML and CSS. I leave a downvote, but after your edition definitely I remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries solved this issue.
Setting a height: ___px for each max-width: ___px.