# Html resize iframe automatically to device size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, autoresize

```
<div  style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px">
        <iframe style="border: none;" src="./RedMan2.html" width="1350" height="900"></iframe>
    </div>
```

How do you automatically resize an iframe to fit the device screen? I just started learning HTML and JS and CSS, so if I did not leave enough code just tell me. I'm only 11. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most modern browsers you can use `vw` and `vh` units which are equal to 1% of screen width and height respectively:

```
<div  style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px">
  <iframe style="border: none; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;" src="./RedMan2.html" width="1350" height="900"></iframe>
</div>
```

If you are targeting old browsers, you can set `width: 100%; height: 100%;` for the `iframe` and its parent `div`:

```
<div  style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <iframe style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="./RedMan2.html" width="1350" height="900"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using
`height: 100vh; width: 100vw;`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/KKzQorY)

More info can be found here: [Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100) :)